# Push notification for android app by GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on android app for events reminder , this app **only display** event as list and details about it .. some event's date is change  .

**I need to push notification to remind a user** about event date

I'am Confused when read about Google Cloud Messaging ( GCM )

- **Is it necessary to request from the user to enter name or email  through the application ?**  I don't need that !
- **where can I write a new notification "message" to send it ?**

Thank you ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement is simple.

You need to generate gcm token from each of your client.

Client A installs your application and upon launch/login(wherever it fits in your business logic) you will try to generate this gcm token(let us say 10000 is the generated token) . And you need to send this token to your server to store for using it in future communication. when you want to communicate with this client A,  you need to tell gcm server,

```
Hey Gcm server, send mobile with gcm token 10000 the following message "Event time updated"
```

So if client b installs, it will generate its gcm token and send it to server in same way.

In case you have user login or some way where each user can be identified uniquely, it is recommended to store it along with user details. (along with name, unique id, etc... )
If you do not have login, you can still send token to server and store but what you loose out is the cases where You want to send update to Client A but not B.

Coming to code point of it.

**Client code:**

*For generating gcm token:*

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

after you generate you need to send this token to server

**Server code:**

server receives the token and stores.

When you want to send a particular message in later point of time, you can send json data or plain message to client. 
For example, Following is the python example.

```
import gcm
response = gcm.json_request(registration_ids=reg_ids, data=in_data, delay_while_idle=False)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you .. I understand little, I will  try .. thank you